# Linux applications bulk installation

Tags: software-installation

Is it possible to execute one script which reads through a file containing a list of packages/applications, tests if each entry is already installed and if not, proceed to install?

I'm trying to find an approach which I can use in installing applications on a number of virgin servers autonomously.

Comment: You could use `dpkg --get-selections > selections` on one computer then `dpkg --set-selections < selections` on the other servers. Also, check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/how-do-i-migrate-configuration-between-computers-with-different-hardware/7397#7397 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79125/reinstalling-all-debian-packages/79165#79165 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/what-i-can-i-do-to-make-the-transition-to-some-new-computer-hardware-safe-and-sm/9400#9400 etc.)

Comment: Yes, but package management depends on the distribution, so you need to tell us which distribution you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try out [Ansible](http://ansible.com).  It's agentless, the only requirement is that your servers are SSH accessible from a host running Ansible (you also need python executable on servers, but you can even automate its installation on the bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing "virgin" servers I highly recommend [FAI](http://fai-project.org/), Fully Automatic Installation, which is designed to set up any number of systems with a pre-defined set of packages and configuration files.

Once the systems are set up, I second [yaegashi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116972/yaegashi)'s recommendation to try out [Ansible](http://ansible.com/).